# Is there API for accessing Kusto data outside Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

What if we have copy files of persistent storage (blobs) for a given Kusto database and want to be able to access these outside Kusto? Is there any way or API available for reading these files? It appears that these are binary files in Kusto's proprietary format so can't just be read without some sort of API/bridge available from Kusto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an API for accessing Kusto data through Kusto: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/.

You really don't want to access the blobs directly as they are stored in a heavily compressed and indexed column store format.  You would have to replicate most of the Kusto database engine to do so.  To do it right, you would effectively end up building another node on your Kusto cluster locally, and it's not clear that you would gain anything from that.  For example, you'd be further from the data, so your queries would be slower.  Better to just ask your Kusto cluster to do the work and send the results.

If you need to access the data using another platform you can .Export it.

If you **really** need to access the data directly, and are willing to sacrifice some performance, then your best bet is probably to store the data outside Kusto and map it as an External Table or use one of the SQL plugins to query the data in it's native format.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the Kusto APIs you can query the data in Kusto using the [Kusto(ADX) spark connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/spark-connector)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access Kusto data from a non-Kusto environment, you need to move the data out of Kusto into SQL or blob storage using the `.export` command.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/data-export/

Comment: What's the point? The Kusto data is already available in blobs , now again you have  to export it out of kusto to some blob defies the whole purpose. The data is already out there in blobs , all I am asking is if there is an API for reading/converting this data. But I think it appears from your answer that there is no way out. That's too bad. Exporting to blob when it's already in a blob is an overkill.

Comment: Yeah but you're not just exporting from blob to blob, you're converting the data into a format that can be easily consumed. The Kusto data is highly compressed/sharded/etc to service a very specialized access pattern. Additionally, if you could access those blobs, then the Kusto service wouldn't be in full control of the access pattern so other services would be contributing to throttling limits, etc.

Comment: "Additionally, if you could access those blobs, then the Kusto service wouldn't be in full control of the access pattern so other services would be contributing to throttling limits, etc" -- your answer is logical. But at broader scale I would say the product should have been designed in such a way so as to leave that choice to customers, what they do with those blobs.

Answer (score 1):

The information isn't duplicated by ADX, it's indexed and compressed by ADX to enable ad-hoc interactive exploration experience.